# Display custom location list based on user location

Tags: drupal, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drupal-7

**Goal:
Display a custom location list on google maps based on the location of the user using geo location.**

The list of locations needs to be given by me so the results will only have locations from my list based on proximity.

I did find the api documentation on google places api but I can't seem to find  any information on how to load your own list and use it in the results.

I am using drupal 7 as my cms. I came across this module but I am not sure of it http://drupal.org/project/location

Kindly help my sharing your views if this can be done ? if yes then please do provide links for me to read further on how to implement this.

Cheers,
Vishal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i understand that you are trying to show users objects which are near them, and you need users location.

you can use google map api's sensor attribute when you add map link to your code.

it will detect user location and then you should use this point to show nearby objects.

Comment: thanks, halil do you know of a good resource that has implemented it. It will save me some time

Comment: i did not know. i implemented boundaries method before. but did not need user location. because i would never say yes when a map in site asks my location. i think this is useless if my site is not a fourquare clon.

Comment: unfortunately the client wants it. thank you for ur time . have a good day

Comment: I am also interested in this.How you manages this?Can you paste the code here?thanks